# Replace every nth line last char with some another char in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to replace every nth line last char with some another char in notepad++

example If I need to modify every 3rd line last char(,) to (;) as below

```
('PS1B2PS6','PS1B 2PS6','35','KPR','-52.7488','47.5660','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2PS7','PS1B 2PS7','35','KPR','-52.7493','47.5644','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2PS8','PS1B 2PS8','35','KPR','-52.7493','47.5644','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2PS9','PS1B 2PS9','35','KPR','-52.7495','47.5639','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2B1','PS1B 2B1','35','KPR','-52.7497','47.5631','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2B2','PS1B 2B2','35','KPR','-52.7500','47.5624','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2B3','PS1B 2B3','35','KPR','-52.7493','47.5666','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2B4','PS1B 2B4','35','KPR','-52.7493','47.5666','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2B5','PS1B 2B5','35','KPR','-52.7503','47.5640','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2B6','PS1B 2B6','35','KPR','-52.7497','47.5673','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2B7','PS1B 2B7','35','KPR','-52.7497','47.5673','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2B8','PS1B 2B8','35','KPR','-52.7519','47.5641','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2B9','PS1B 2B9','35','KPR','-52.7519','47.5641','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
```

It should come as

```
('PS1B2PS6','PS1B 2PS6','35','KPR','-52.7488','47.5660','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2PS7','PS1B 2PS7','35','KPR','-52.7493','47.5644','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2PS8','PS1B 2PS8','35','KPR','-52.7493','47.5644','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0);
('PS1B2PS9','PS1B 2PS9','35','KPR','-52.7495','47.5639','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2B1','PS1B 2B1','35','KPR','-52.7497','47.5631','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2B2','PS1B 2B2','35','KPR','-52.7500','47.5624','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0);
('PS1B2B3','PS1B 2B3','35','KPR','-52.7493','47.5666','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2B4','PS1B 2B4','35','KPR','-52.7493','47.5666','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2B5','PS1B 2B5','35','KPR','-52.7503','47.5640','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0);
('PS1B2B6','PS1B 2B6','35','KPR','-52.7497','47.5673','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2B7','PS1B 2B7','35','KPR','-52.7497','47.5673','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
('PS1B2B8','PS1B 2B8','35','KPR','-52.7519','47.5641','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0);
('PS1B2B9','PS1B 2B9','35','KPR','-52.7519','47.5641','CPS','MARK','MARK','MARK','MARK',0),
```

So can someone please help me here.

Comment: Replace `^(?:.*\r\n){2}.*\K,` with a semicolon